# Run migrations on MongoDB Atlas with Go

Tags: database, mongodb, go, database-migration, mongodb-atlas

I'm looking for a Go module to make Mongo Atlas database migrations. So far I've found [golang-migrate](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4), but it only supports MongoDB and not Mongo Atlas. I'm trying to automate creating and dropping Atlas Search Indexes. The only other option I'm aware of is via Atlas CLI or APIs but it would be way lot more easier if there already exists a solution taking care of versioning and managing the state of migrations.